# Как правильно выбрать индексы для таблицы базы данных по приведённому примеру?

Tags: база-данных, index, индексы

Есть некоторая таблица, в ней Id с авто инкрементом, несколько различных текстовых полей, а главное есть 2 поля с int данными в которых хранится некоторый числовой диапазон, который в других записях этой таблицы не пересекается(это базой контролировать не требуется, данные так загружены что диапазоны не пересекаются). То есть первое поле хранит число начала диапазона а второе его конечное. Давайте для условности пусть будут поля `id`,`min`,`max`.

Меня интересует запрос вида SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE (`min` < N) AND (`max` > N); где N некоторое подставляемое число.

Вопрос не только как правильно выбрать индекс для `min` и `max` поля, а так же почему? Исходя из того что я прочитал в книгах, видимо правильнее сделать один индекс по обоим полям `min` и `max`, вот только я не понял почему. На мой взгляд если сделать отдельные по этим полям то вроде бы тоже понятно что должно нормально работать. Я просто представляю что ищется по одному индексу по другому а затем берётся их объединение? А как  в случаи с объединёным индексом работает выборка, можно более детально как то расписать саму теорию или даже физический смысл как работает объединённый индекс? Если можно как то распишите на примере каких нибудь 10 записей, то есть как для них будет выглядеть индекс и чтобы было наглядно видно что он действительно быстрее чем 2 индекса по двум полям.

Answer (score 0):

> Меня интересует запрос вида `` SELECT id FROM table WHERE (`min` < N) AND (`max` > N); `` где N некоторое подставляемое число.
>
> Вопрос не только как правильно выбрать индекс для min и max поля, а так же почему?

Правильно с точки зрения производительности - изменить схему хранения. Использовать GEOMETRY и соответственно Spatial Index.

Если это невозможно, то следует использовать покрывающий индекс - по `` (`min`, `max`, id) `` либо `` (`max`, `min`, id) ``.

> Исходя из того что я прочитал в книгах, видимо правильнее сделать один индекс по обоим полям min и max

Плохо читал. У тебя неравенство - соответственно индекс будет использован только для одного условия, того, для которого поле в выражении индекса первое.

> На мой взгляд если сделать отдельные по этим полям то вроде бы тоже понятно что должно нормально работать.

Неверно. Одна копия таблицы в источнике запроса может использовать только один индекс.

---

С точки зрения максимальной эффективности, с учётом гарантии, что диапазоны не пересекаются (то есть запрос возвращает либо одну запись, либо пустой набор данных), и при нежелании использовать spatial datatypes, запрос следует переписать так:

```
SELECT id
FROM ( SELECT id 
       FROM table
       WHERE `min` < N
       ORDER BY `min` LIMIT 1 ) t1
JOIN ( SELECT id
       FROM table t2
       WHERE `max` > N 
       ORDER BY `max` DESC LIMIT 1 ) t2 USING (id)
```

и создать два индекса - `` (`min`, id) `` и `` (`max`, id) ``. Но это мероприятие имеет смысл только в случае, если таблица реально ну очень большая (размером в гигабайты и записей под миллиард).

Comment: Не понял из написанного вами как же правильно(не то что бы плохо написали, просто нет однозначности в ответе). "Плохо читал." - там имелось ввиду общий индекс по 2-м полям. "покрывающий индекс - по (min, max, id)" - а id то зачем? По нему же поиск не идёт? Можете ли Вы привести пример индекса для MySQL который был бы правильным для данной задачи? (Извините если что, я просто уже описал я просто видимо не понял как работает объединённый индекс с точки зрения простой логики, то есть как именно он работает, возможно из за этого у меня и не понимание, одиночный индекс я вроде понимаю как работает)

Comment: @skvernoslov Специально ещё раз ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО прочитайте всё по термину "покрывающий индекс" (covering index) - особенно насчёт того, почему он эффективен по сравнению с фуллсканом даже в случае, если его выражение не соответствует тексту запроса.

Comment: Ок. А можно ещё ссылку или ссылки на статьи которые Вы считаете адекватными и содержащими достаточную информацию для понимания вопроса "покрывающих индексов"? Просто если я сам что то найду по теме мало ли чего то там не написали или написали не совсем верно.

Comment: @skvernoslov Добавил ещё вариант в ответ. Насчёт литературы не подскажу - уже давно не пользуюсь и не слежу, мне хватает Reference Manual. Насчёт покрывающего индекса - он просто используется как компактный вариант таблицы (требуется меньше дисковых чтений), и обращения к собственно таблице не требуется, все значения извлекаются прямо из индекса. Без `id` в индексе - после поиска по индексу надо ещё в саму таблицу сбегать за `id`, а это лишние дисковые операции.